# App crashes on API level below 21 caused by Fancy Buttons

Tags: android, libraries

I am testing my app on a bunch of different API levels just to double check that it worked as I intended but at any level less then 21 it crashes and dumps the exceptions that I put below. I've tried moving the order of the dependencies and I've made sure the library is in my libs folder. This happened when I added google services to my dependencies and enabled multidex

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.schweigert.will.tweettunes.TwitterLoginFragment.onCreateView(TwitterLoginFragment.java:46)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.schweigert.will.tweettunes-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.schweigert.will.tweettunes-2, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.schweigert.will.tweettunes.TwitterLoginFragment.onCreateView(TwitterLoginFragment.java:46)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the line that the exception is thrown

`View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.twitter_login_fragment, container, false);`

Comment: Are you sure about this library "mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton"  ,Is this library support lower than 21? What is your min sdk version?

Comment: please check the sample given in that library  compare it with your gradle. 
https://github.com/medyo/Fancybuttons/blob/master/samples/build.gradle

Comment: Ok my min sdk is 14. I believe this library supports as low as 8. Unless I'm mistaken that is shown here https://github.com/medyo/Fancybuttons/blob/master/fancybuttons_library/build.gradle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Multidex support for Android 5.0 and higher**

> Android 5.0 and higher uses a runtime called ART which natively
>   supports loading multiple dex files from application APK files. ART
>   performs pre-compilation at application install time which scans for
>   classes(..N).dex files and compiles them into a single .oat file for
>   execution by the Android device. For more information on the Android
>   5.0 runtime, see Introducing ART.

That means your app would working fine on API level 21 or above.

**Multidex support prior to Android 5.0**

> Versions of the platform prior to Android 5.0 use the Dalvik runtime
>   for executing app code. By default, Dalvik limits apps to a single
>   classes.dex bytecode file per APK. In order to get around this
>   limitation, you can use the multidex support library, which becomes
>   part of the primary DEX file of your app and then manages access to
>   the additional DEX files and the code they contain.

So, Firstly making sure you have imported correct dependency, which It seems you did it.

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

In your manifest add the `MultiDexApplication` class from the multidex support library to the application element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Alternative to that, If your app extends the `Application` class, you can override the `attachBaseContext()` method and call `MultiDex.install(this)` to enable `multidex`.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {
    MultiDex.install(getTargetContext());
    super.onCreate(arguments);
    ...
}
```

Finally, you will need to update your build.gradle file as below by adding `multiDexEnabled true` :

```
defaultConfig {  
        applicationId '{Project Name}'  
        minSdkVersion 15  
        targetSdkVersion 23  
        versionCode 1  
        versionName "1.0"  
        multiDexEnabled true  
    }
```

I hope it will help you out.

Comment: Wow look at this answer. Sorry for getting back to you so late. I'll try all of this out tomorrow and if it works I'll throw you some of those sweet sweet Internet points

Comment: Thank you so much! Just used your suggestions and now everything is running smoothly!